# Finding which shape contains coordinates (over function) using R?

Tags: shapefile, r

I'm working in R and I am new to maps and GIS and I have no idea how it works. But I am trying to return which part of the city specific coordinates are located.
I got the shapefile from here:

> https://opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/ac4e22c0d8444b8b81a0ee9af3273f40_2.zip

I read the file and transform it:

```
library(rgdal)
library(mapview)    
nhood <- readOGR(dsn = "hverfahlutar.shp")
nhood2 = spTransform(nhood, CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"))
```

the dataframe I am working with is this:

```
schools <- structure(list(school = skolar <- c("Vesturbæjarskóli", "Landakotsskóli", 
                      "Barnaskóli Hjallastefnunnar í Reykjavík ", "Tjarnarskóli", "Austurbæjarskóli", 
                      "Langholtsskóli", "Vogaskóli", "Suðurhlíðarskóli", "Brúarskóli", 
                      "Hlíðaskóli"), long = c(64.1497778, 64.1478234, 64.1287022, 64.1406399, 
                                              64.1417735, 64.1380849, 64.131696, 64.1216781, 64.1256253, 64.130929
                      ), lat = c(-21.959836, -21.9517121, -21.9311303, -21.9365311, 
                                 -21.9237807, -21.8623288, -21.8606524, -21.9040609, -21.9130514, 
                                 -21.9122735)), .Names = c("school", "long", "lat"), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                   -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I can plot it with points so the data seems to be okay:

```
plot(nhood2)
points(schools$long ~ schools$lat, col = "red", cex = 1)
```

What to do next I do not know. I think I need to use the over function but it has not been working for me.

What I need to do is, for each coordinates in each row of school. I need to return the corresponding value in nhood2$HEITI (the name of the neighbourhood.)

I think I need to prepare the data in the schools dataframe for this, but I don't understand how... or why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `schools` isn't a data frame, its a "tibble". You should convert it to a real data frame, and then assign its coordinates to create a Spatial Points Data Frame. Also you've got your lat-long the wrong way round, so I'll rename the columns:

```
library(sp)
schools = data.frame(schools)
names(schools) = c("school","lat","long")
coordinates(schools)=~long+lat
```

Your points and polygons are using the same coordinate system now, so set the schools projection to the same as nhood2 - there's no transformation done here, its just marking the coordinate system:

```
proj4string(schools) = proj4string(nhood2)
```

*Don't* use tibbles if you are working with spatial data and the `sp` package (which is what `rgdal` also returns).

Then you can overlay points with polygons:

```
> over(schools, nhood2)
   OBJECTID                 DAGS_INN  NOTANDI     HEITI DAGS_UPPR DAGS_LEIDR
1      4664 2002-07-30T12:48:16.000Z LUK_GOGN   Grandar      <NA>       <NA>
2      4671 2002-07-30T12:48:16.000Z LUK_GOGN Vesturbær      <NA>       <NA>
3      4694 2002-07-30T12:48:16.000Z LUK_GOGN Vatnsmýri      <NA>       <NA>
4      4709 2002-07-30T12:48:16.000Z LUK_GOGN Austurbær      <NA>       <NA>
5      4709 2002-07-30T12:48:16.000Z LUK_GOGN Austurbær      <NA>       <NA>
6      4700 2002-07-30T12:48:16.000Z LUK_GOGN    Heimar      <NA>       <NA>
7      4700 2002-07-30T12:48:16.000Z LUK_GOGN    Heimar      <NA>       <NA>
8      4681 2002-07-30T12:48:16.000Z LUK_GOGN Öskjuhlíð      <NA>       <NA>
9      4674 2002-07-30T12:48:16.000Z LUK_GOGN    Hlíðar      <NA>       <NA>
10     4674 2002-07-30T12:48:16.000Z LUK_GOGN    Hlíðar      <NA>       <NA>
```

This has the `HEITI` column from the polygons for each point, as well as all the other columns from the polygons.

You might also want to look into how to do this using `sf` class objects, a newer system for spatial data.

Comment: Thank you very much.
I had forgotten about it being tibble as I was working with a older dataset (and the addiction to using the dplyr package).

I plan to just join the dataframes to get the name of the school in the corresponding row... but, is there a way to add the school column from the school variable to the new overlay dataframe?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution with sf. In this case, you can leave it as a tibble.

```
library(sf)
# since you mentioned in the comment you used dplyr I thought you wouldn't mind this dependency, used for filter
library(dplyr)

nhood <- st_read('input/HVERFAHEITI.shp')
names(schools) = c("school","lat","long")
schools <-  st_as_sf(schools, coords = c("long", "lat"), crs = 4326)

# this shows which neighbourhoods (HEITI) intersects each school
st_join(schools, nhood['HEITI'], join = st_intersects)

>#                                    school     HEITI                   geometry
># 1                          Vesturbæjarskóli   Grandar POINT (-21.95984 64.14978)
># 2                            Landakotsskóli Vesturbær POINT (-21.95171 64.14782)
># 3  Barnaskóli Hjallastefnunnar í Reykjavík  Vatnsmýri  POINT (-21.93113 64.1287)
># 4                              Tjarnarskóli Austurbær POINT (-21.93653 64.14064)
># 5                          Austurbæjarskóli Austurbær POINT (-21.92378 64.14177)
># 6                            Langholtsskóli    Heimar POINT (-21.86233 64.13808)
># 7                                 Vogaskóli    Heimar  POINT (-21.86065 64.1317)
># 8                          Suðurhlíðarskóli Öskjuhlíð POINT (-21.90406 64.12168)
># 9                                Brúarskóli    Hlíðar POINT (-21.91305 64.12563)
># 10                               Hlíðaskóli    Hlíðar POINT (-21.91227 64.13093)
```

I'm not totally clear on what you are requesting in your comment, but if you would like to subset which nhood polygons have a school in it and add the school variable (i.e. add school to nhood object, rather than nhood to school object), this should work:

```
st_join(nhood['HEITI'], schools, join = st_intersects) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(school)) %>% 
  as.data.frame()

>#         HEITI                                   school                       geometry
># 1  Austurbær                             Tjarnarskóli MULTIPOLYGON (((-21.92646 6...
># 2  Austurbær                         Austurbæjarskóli MULTIPOLYGON (((-21.92646 6...
># 3     Heimar                           Langholtsskóli MULTIPOLYGON (((-21.8594 64...
># 4     Heimar                                Vogaskóli MULTIPOLYGON (((-21.8594 64...
># 5    Grandar                         Vesturbæjarskóli MULTIPOLYGON (((-21.96228 6...
># 6  Vesturbær                           Landakotsskóli MULTIPOLYGON (((-21.94349 6...
># 7     Hlíðar                               Brúarskóli MULTIPOLYGON (((-21.9185 64...
># 8     Hlíðar                               Hlíðaskóli MULTIPOLYGON (((-21.9185 64...
># 9  Öskjuhlíð                         Suðurhlíðarskóli MULTIPOLYGON (((-21.91542 6...
># 10 Vatnsmýri Barnaskóli Hjallastefnunnar í Reykjavík  MULTIPOLYGON (((-21.94523 6...
```